# Ubuntu 23.10 problem with sound, no bass

Tags: sound, 23.10

Problem with sound, no bass. Previously, in the pulse configuration I did the following:
"How to Resolve no sound problem on Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10, 13.04 and Older versions
The fix is quite easy to apply (but it was not easy to find the right one!).
First of all edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and add this line at the end:

load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe

then edit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, modify the line “enable-lfe-remixing: no” to “enable-lfe-remixing: yes“, then uncomment it (remove the semicolon in front of it). Reboot your PC and enjoy the subwoofer!
NEW VERSION!! remixing-produce-lfe = yes"

Now these files are not in the system at all or they are in a different place. How to fix 5.1 sound so that the subwoofer plays normally?
Help! :D